# Using lstinline in caption of lstlistings with multicol?

Tags: listings, captions, multicol

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\def\extra{extra}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  multicols=2,
  caption={
    [short] aaaa \extra, \lstinline{asf_sdf}
  },
]
LDPT_NULL = 0,
LDPT_API_VERSION,
LDPT_GOLD_VERSION,
LDPT_LINKER_OUTPUT,
\end{lstlisting}
```

It crashes with:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

It will not crash if `multicols` is commented - or if `multicols` is left, and `\lstinline` is commented. EDIT - and also, `\protect\lstinline{asf_sdf}` does not help.

How can I use all these commands together?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

The `listings` documentation (see subsection 5.8) states that

> the multicolumn option is known to fail with some keys.

If you can afford to do without `\lstinline`, use a custom macro instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\inlinecode[1]
  {\lst@basicstyle #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\extra{extra}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  multicols=2,
  caption={
    [short] aaaa \extra, \inlinecode{asf\_sdf}
  },
]
LDPT_NULL = 0,
LDPT_API_VERSION,
LDPT_GOLD_VERSION,
LDPT_LINKER_OUTPUT,
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```